# Online service to download file from URL directly as zip

Tags: malware, web-service, tools

Is there an online service which allows to download a file from a URL directly zipped?

I want to analyze a potential malicious JavaScript file with some automatic anti virus engines but I don't want to download the file unzipped. Furthermore my network's proxy settings are blocking an unzipped download due to a blacklisted MD5 hash value of the file itself.

Comment: Download it from somewhere else, e.g. a vm in azure or google cloud.

Comment: WRT, `Furthermore my ISP's proxy settings are blocking an unzipped download due to a blacklisted MD5 hash value of the file itself.` - are you downloading the file by http or https?  If https, then your ISP would have no way of blocking the file, because they would have no way of knowing the md5 checksum of the file, or anything about the content of the file for that matter.

Comment: @mti2935 it's a secured network which is interfering the traffic via an installed root certificate on all machines in the network.

Comment: @vidarlo isn't there a simple service which allows to exactly do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to download the `.js` file as `.txt` via https://lookyloo.circl.lu